# How to maximize this value?

Tags: combinatorics

For $$z = 1 - [(x_1)(x_1 - 1) + ... + (x_n)(x_n - 1)]/[(2^y)(2^y-1)]$$ where $x_1 + ... + x_n = y,$ where $y$ and $n$ are fixed, what values of $x_i,$ minimize $z$? I know from high school calculus how to figure this sort of thing for one variable, but don’t know what to do when there’s more than one. I would also appreciate resources for learning more about this sort of thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The simplest way is to use the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier):
$$\forall i: -2x_i+1-\lambda=0\implies
\forall i: x_i=\frac{1-\lambda}2\implies x_i=\frac yn.
$$
It remains to check if the extreme point is indeed maximum.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! One last question: how can we find the extrema of this function? I know how to find the extrema of functions with two dimensional constraints, but I haven't been able to find the extrema of functions with more variables.

Comment: Generally a function takes a global maximum (or minimum) either at local maximum (or minimum) in the interior of the domain, or on the boundary of the doman. In your case domain is unbounded. Therefore the function has the only extremum (given in the answer).